# Determining which domain a problem falls into in the Cynefin framework falls into which domain itself?

Tags: task-management

The [Cynefin framework](https://www.mindtools.com/pages/article/cynefin-framework.htm) is a tool to help leaders determine which 'domain' a problem falls into which they seek to solve.

Proponents of the framework argue that the approach towards solving a problem should be different depending on which domain the problem falls into, and that the framework aids problem solving in this regard.

Determining which domain a problem falls into in the Cynefin framework can be considered a problem in itself. Which domain does this fall into?

At first it may seem that the problem falls into the simple domain, because it's just a matter of simple categorisation.

However, some may argue that it falls into the complicated domain, because it requires prior research about the Cynefin framework itself, and because for some problems it can be a close call between two domains and difficult to decide.

Comment: That's a curious question - what are you trying to achieve with the answer for it?

Comment: @TiagoCardoso I had the same question, but reading between the lines I would guess that the OP isn't sure how to categorize categorization with the project management discipline. I'm glad you asked the question directly, though!

Comment: I wrote my answer based on the assumption that you want to find people with the right knowledge and experience to perform regular investigations of problems, but you don't want them to spend a lot of time on work that could be performed by someone more junior. Defining the domain that investigations falls into can guide recruitment etc.

Answer (score 1):

### Categorization is Generally Useful for Resource Allocation and Planning

There are lots of frameworks that provide some level of triage or categorization, including:

- [Cynefin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynefin_framework)
- [MoSCoW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MoSCoW_method)
- [Product Backlog](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#product-backlog)
- [Eisenhower Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_management#The_Eisenhower_Method)
- [Planning Poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planning_poker)

and tons of others. From a pragmatic perspective, they all provide some sort of data to inform *resource allocation* decisions. Since all projects have resource constraints, having a way to identify which things will require more time, money, equipment, people, or anything else that's a limited resource may be useful in prioritization, scheduling, or planning.

Answer (score 0):

**Depends on the problem itself, but if you want to be able to handle any problem it's Complex. If you only want to determine the problem type but not solve it, you can get away with Complicated in most but not all cases.**

Generally speaking, an investigation process can determine if a problem is of the same level as the investigation itself. This is often used in customer support, where the first investigation is **Obvious** and based on scripted questions and work flows. If the problem is obvious, the solution is already known and will eventually be found in the script.

If the problem is not obvious, then this type of investigation will only reveal that the problem could not be solved this way. So you send the problem along to a **Complicated** investigation process. This would usually require a person experienced with the field to see if the problem is similar (but not exactly the same) as other problems they have encountered in the past.

If the problem is not complicated, then you can assume that it is complex. Just make sure that the problem is actually well defined. If you have a **Disordered** problem where there is a big disconnect between the actual problem and the way the problem is communicated and understood, you may have a situation where you later find out that the problem was obvious all along but misunderstood. This will be found out once you try to solve it as a complex problem, which is generally a waste of resources.

Actually solving this problem would require experimentation and dialogue with the customer/client in order to gain knowledge of the issue and to try out different ideas for solving it. However, before doing this there is still the need to carry out a **Complex** investigation to try to get a feeling for if the problem is worth putting effort into, based on the limited information available.

This flow, or some simplified version of it, can be handled by only having a Complex investigation structure in place, but that it usually isn't cost effective because of the high need for a variety of experienced (and probably highly paid) people.

As a side note, if you do happen to encounter a problem that is actually **Chaotic** for you, this is usually a sign that there are issues with your organisation and your way of conducting investigations. This is more of a responsibility of your company leadership, so that processes and structure can be established first before any work is done. At this point, it should be possible to convert these types of issues into another easier type, by just making someone empowered to actually perform any investigation at all.